# Cannot convert value of type '([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void' to expect argument type 'CLGeocodeCompletionHandler'

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, core-location

I wanted to jump over to use Xcode 7.3.1 and convert my code, but I'm facing some kind of problem here, this is how I used to use it in Swift 1.1 but I am getting error:

> Cannot convert value of type '([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void' to expect argument type 'CLGeocodeCompletionHandler' (aka '(Optional>, Optional)-> ()'):

Here is my code:

```
  private func geoCodeAddress(address:NSString){

    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address as String, completionHandler: {(place marks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in ---> Error //Cannot convert value of type '([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void' to expect argument type 'CLGeocodeCompletionHandler' (aka '(Optional<Array<CLPlacemark>>, Optional<NSError>)-> ()')

        if (error != nil) {                
            self.geocodingCompletionHandler!(gecodeInfo:nil,placemark:nil,error: error.localizedDescription)                
        }
        else{

            if let placemark = placemarks?[0] as? CLPlacemark {

                var address = AddressParser()
                address.parseAppleLocationData(placemark)
                let addressDict = address.getAddressDictionary()
                self.geocodingCompletionHandler!(gecodeInfo: addressDict,placemark:placemark,error: nil)
            }
            else {
                self.geocodingCompletionHandler!(gecodeInfo: nil,placemark:nil,error: "invalid address: \(address)")                    
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the error message, `CLGeocodeCompletionHandler` returns optional not a concrete object so just change the completionHandler code to

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

})
```